# How do I call a function on stdout from a child process?

Tags: function, process, call

I have a child process calling the cat command on words piped in from stdin and out to stdout. How can I call a function removeDups() before the child process is replaced by that cat process?

fyi removeDups() will capture the piped words, remove any duplicates, record the frequency, and send the word list back to the child process to print out to screen or print out to screen directly. Here's a code snippet (more like pseudocode):

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
//...Child case(from fork() switch above):
case 0:
    execl("/bin/cat", "cat", (char *) NULL);
}

char[][] removeDups()
{
    char uniqueWords[MAX_WORDS][BUF_SIZE];
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    while (fscanf(stdin, "%s", buf) != EOF)
    {
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < MAX; ++k)
        {
            if (strcmp(uniqueWords[k], buf) == 0)
            {
                found = 1;
                frequency[k]++;
            }
        }
        int l;
        if (found == 0)
        {
            strcpy(uniqueWords[l], buf);
            ++l;
        {
    }
    return uniqueWords;
}
```

[Edit: I realized it may be better not to use the cat command at all. Still, any tips would be appreciated. Thx]

Comment: Perhaps needless to say, you can't return arrays like this in C.

Answer (score 0):

You really should compile your code with `gcc -Wall`; your `removeDups` cannot work because it returns an automatic local array.

You need to learn more about `fork`, `execve` and [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and [dup2(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup2.2.html) syscalls. Perhaps [popen(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/popen.3.html) could be also useful to you.

I strongly suggest reading some good book like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which has a chapter about these things.

Comment: Granted, but for now what's the idea behind taking a file stream and altering it before releasing to stdout (with cat process)?

Comment: Where are you "altering a file stream" ??